# how to encrypt password like Laravel Hashing directly in table column

Tags: laravel, database, encryption, hash

I am new to Laravel. How to do password encryption  like Laravel hashing directly in table column, like md5(Not using code, I want to go and directly edit column value)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D87h0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElR6i.png)

Comment: What do you mean "_directly in table column_"? Also, [`encryption`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) and [`hashing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a simple php code and use [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, or just use online `password_hash` tool like [this](https://phppasswordhash.com/). The value will be valid hashed password that can be used, since `Hash::make` in Laravel uses `password_hash` too ([Laravel Framework Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php#L45)).

Comment: I used "password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)" in my registration.If i want to directly edit it in the database how to do.Please check the images attached

Comment: @SITHARA I've described in my answer, you could use online tools, and then use the result to edit your password in database directly. Also you don't need to use MD5 func in database. Another thing, you could use `Hash::make` instead of `password_hash` in Laravel.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. Now it is clear

Answer (score 0):

So, as it was suggested in the previous answer, you can use online tools to hash and then edit the column (if I understood you right), otherwise, you can use `php artisan tinker` to do `Hash::make(something)` and get the expected hash

Comment: If it was suggested in the previous answer then what value does your answer add?